# Adding a 2D array using cooperative threads

Tags: java

I am trying to add a 2D array using cooperative threads. But i am getting answer of only the last thread. I have 3 threads only. My code is:

```
public class Arr2DThreadAdd {
static int[ ] [ ] arr2D ={{10, 20, 30, 40}, {11, 12, 13, 14}, {12, 13, 14, 15}};
static int[ ] result = new int[3];

static class job extends Thread{
    int arr2Mindex;

    job(int index){
      arr2Mindex= index;     
   }
    public void run(){
       int i;
       int sum=0;


        for( i=0;i<4; ++i)
            sum = sum +arr2D[arr2Mindex][i];

        result[arr2Mindex]= sum;

    }
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        job[] obj = new job[3];
        for(int i=0; i<3; ++i){
            obj[i]= new job(i);
            obj[i].start();
            try{
                obj[i].join();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
    String res="";

   for( int j= 0; j<3; ++j)
      res = result[j] + " ";
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, res);
    }

}
```

Right now i am getting only 54 which is the correct answer for the last e,ement of 2D array i.e. `{12, 13, 14, 15}`

When i checked the following line:

```
obj[i]= new job(i);
```

by passing values like

```
obj[i]= new job(0);
```

or

```
obj[i] = new job(1);
```

I am getting zero in both the above cases. However when i typed:

```
obj[i] = new job(2);
```

I got **54.**

Somebody please guide me what is the problem in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the result value instead of adding to it in your loop.

Change

```
res = result[j] + " ";
```

to

```
res = res + result[j] + " ";
```

and you'll get all of the results.

Answer (score 0):

The error is you are not appending it to the existing string, rather replacing it, hence only the last value remains at the end. change it like so,

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    res += result[j] + " ";
```